# Sort a tsv by date with python script

Tags: python, django, csv

How can I reorder the arrangement of values in my TSV to be sorted by date. The current arrangement is by the first column, but I want to overwrite the file with the same data only arranged by date.

The current format is as shows:

```
param1 | param2 | param3 | date | param5 | param6 |
```

Sample content:

```
1000045|sample 1|10-Q|2021-02-11|edgar/data/1000045/0001564590-21-005399.txt|edgar/data/1000045/0001564590-21-005399-index.html
1000045|sample 1|4/A|2021-02-12|edgar/data/1000045/0001398344-21-003309.txt|edgar/data/1000045/0001398344-21-003309-index.html
1000045|sample 1|4|2021-02-08|edgar/data/1000045/0001496701-21-000001.txt|edgar/data/1000045/0001496701-21-000001-index.html
1000045|sample 1|4|2021-02-09|edgar/data/1000045/0001398344-21-002769.txt|edgar/data/1000045/0001398344-21-002769-index.html
1000045|sample 1|8-K|2021-01-25|edgar/data/1000045/0001564590-21-002004.txt|edgar/data/1000045/0001564590-21-002004-index.html
1000045|sample 1|8-K|2021-02-03|edgar/data/1000045/0001564590-21-003940.txt|edgar/data/1000045/0001564590-21-003940-index.html
1000045|sample 1|8-K|2021-03-08|edgar/data/1000045/0001564590-21-011365.txt|edgar/data/1000045/0001564590-21-011365-index.html
1000045|sample 1|SC 13G/A|2021-02-08|edgar/data/1000045/0001104659-21-013485.txt|edgar/data/1000045/0001104659-21-013485-index.html
1000045|sample 1|SC 13G/A|2021-02-11|edgar/data/1000045/0001037389-21-000122.txt|edgar/data/1000045/0001037389-21-000122-index.html
1000045|sample 1|SC 13G/A|2021-02-12|edgar/data/1000045/0000354204-21-000071.txt|edgar/data/1000045/0000354204-21-000071-index.html
1000097|sample 2|13F-HR|2021-02-16|edgar/data/1000097/0001000097-21-000004.txt|edgar/data/1000097/0001000097-21-000004-index.html
1000097|sample 2|SC 13G|2021-01-11|edgar/data/1000097/0000919574-21-000165.txt|edgar/data/1000097/0000919574-21-000165-index.html
1000177|sample 3|SC 13G/A|2021-01-29|edgar/data/1000177/0000834237-21-004594.txt|edgar/data/1000177/0000834237-21-004594-index.html
```

I tried using bash but it needs to run at the same time as the script I will use.

The current script I have is like this:

```
def edgar_filings_download(date): 
    try:
        # code to rearrange the file
        with open(edgar_path + filename, 'r') as file:
            tsv_file = list(csv.reader(file, delimiter='|'))
            _CHECK = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
            start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(tsv_file[len(tsv_file) - 1][3], "%Y-%m-%d")
            end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(tsv_file[0][3], "%Y-%m-%d")
            if start_date <= _CHECK <= end_date:
                logger.debug('pass')
            else:
                logger.debug('no pass')
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)
```

As you may see, I am using the first and last lines as the range of the dates I want to check so I don't have to check line by line. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort and rewrite the file like this:-

```
import csv

with open('edgar.tsv', 'r+') as tsv:
    tsv_file = sorted(list(csv.reader(tsv, delimiter='|')), key=lambda t: t[3])
    tsv.seek(0)
    for line in tsv_file:
        tsv.write('|'.join(line) + '\n')
```

Comment: This worked great! Thanks. Although I have to wonder, would it be better for me to rewrite the files before doing the latter script?